# Properties location

Tags: java, properties

I need to create a properties file to store username/passwords for DBs and other websites for my application.

Is there a good place to put this?

I was thinking of putting in /usr/local/myapp/myapp.properties

However...this doesnt really make much sense for Windows boxes. However, I don't want to store it under a particular user's account as I want it to be global for all users.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Add it anywhere you feel like so (according to windows folder policies) and set a system environment variable so you can find it through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it wherever you like, and point your application to it via a vm parameter: `-Dproperties.location=/usr/local/...`

Then you can read it with `System.getProperty("properties.location")`

Comment: adding spring to the picture makes the question a bit different. You can ask a new one, I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built-in [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class, the values will be automatically saved in the appropriate place on the user's system.

**Edit:**

Oops, I missed the "global to all users" requirement. This will not work on all systems in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I have written on this property framework for the last year.
It will provide of multiple ways to load properties, and have them strongly typed as well. Which also include a way to encrypt/decrypt a password property.

Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhpropertiestyp/

JHPropertiesTyped will give the developer strongly typed properties.
Easy to integrate in existing projects.
Handled by a large series for property types.
Gives the ability to one-line initialize properties via property IO implementations.
Gives the developer the ability to create own property types and property io's. 
Web demo is also available, screenshots shown above.
Also have a standard implementation for a web front end to manage properties, if you choose to use it.

Complete documentation, tutorial, javadoc, faq etc is a available on the project webpage.