# tell java program where is properties file

Tags: java

I have done java program that I'm trying to install to linux machine. Unfortunately my program doesn't sees property file and gets default values. What is the way of telling java where is property file placed?

```
Program is placed in:
/opt/myProg

Properties are placed in:
/opt/myProg/config.ini


external jar:
/opt/myProg/lib

classes in packeges:
/opt/myProg/Prog


Command I'm trying to run my program:
java -cp /opt/myProg/lib/log4j.jar:/opt/myProg/Prog:/opt/myProg/. startpkg.runme
```

This command also does't helps:

```
java -cp /opt/myProg/lib/log4j.jar:/opt/myProg/Prog:/opt/myProg/. startpkg.runme -Dconfig.ini=/opt/myProg/config.ini
```

code that is trying to load props looks like:

```
p.load(new FileInputStream("config.ini"));
```

Comment: use -DconfigFile=/whatever/properties.pros and in your code just access it with System.getProperty("configFile")

Comment: 1/ Where is your properties 2/ How do you load it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150990/confused-about-java-properties-file-location

Comment: -1 You omit vital information. What does the code look like that you wrote to load the properties file? Or are you trying to configure log4j?

Comment: I have updated my question with required information

Comment: FileInputStream is going to look in the current directory.

Comment: ... and current directory is System.getProperty("user.dir") on all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use maven directory structure. Put all properties in src/main/resources and load them with

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
```